Restoring lost contact through iOS SFMC SDK
if I delete contact in SFMC via website that is associated with mobile app, that results in "ghost" app that has no device ID and no contact, then how can I recreate this contact using SFMC SDK programmatically?
Regular on launch setup does not work and SMFC Sdk returns status of inactive. Removing app completely and installing it again works but would rather avoid that.
